# Tricky wordpress setup with redirect from another server

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I could use some advice as to how to migrate from my local staging server to my production server. Its a rather tricky setup so bare with my as I try to describe it.

I have my site set up and working great at the root of a staging subdomain on my personal server.
Staging: staging.mydomain.com

later this week I'm going to be moving it to a new production server on Rackspace which currently has no domains attached to it (is just an IP address). The clients is redirecting a folder to the new rackspace server.
http://www.clientsdomain.com/subfolder/
This will be where the site lives. But clientsdomain.com is a different server somewhere else in the world (not at rackspace). they will be redirecting traffic to that url to the new rackspace server.

So my questions are:
my working staging set up for wordpress is at the root of my personal servers subdomain. How should I set it up on rackspace? At the root of the ip address? or within a subfolder to mimic the domain setup for any relative links.

The reason I ask is that I thought i had this set up properly....But...

I went ahead and attempted to move the site onto my Rackspace server into a dev folder. My client set up a dev url

http://www.clientsdomain.com/dev/subfolder/

Anyone visiting that url will get redirected to my server (my rackspace server simply has an ip address)

the sites front end works with absolute urls. But where things start to fail is within wp-admin. If for example i'm on the General Settings page and click save. It saves the data and then redirects to /wp-admin/... instead of /dev/subfolder/wp-admin/. Since that folder doesn't exist it goes to my clients 404 page.

Also, going to
http://www.clientsdomain.com/dev/subfolder/wp-admin ends on the clients servers 404 page but...

http://www.clientsdomain.com/dev/subfolder/wp-admin/ (with slash) works properly.

The way I moved the site to Rackspace from my dev folder was to change the URLs in wp-admin on my server (which was staging.mydomain.com) to
http://www.clientsdomain.com/dev/subfolder/

I then saved those settings, downloaded the db and site files and uploaded the files and database to rackspace and changed the wp-config file to match the rackspace db.

This is my current htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would REALLY appreciated some guidance here. supposed to be going live on Tuesday.

Thanks!
Fish

Answer (score 0):

I recently setup a WordPress installation on a standard domain (www.domain.com) but had to move it over to another domain which had a subdomain (blog.newdomain.com). I found I was experiencing very similar problems to you, especially with wp-admin redirecting to the previous domain which no longer existed.

I came across a handy search and replace tool for MySQL databases (available at http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and replaced all instances of the original www.domain.com with the new blog.newdomain.com and it corrected all my issues.

I hope this information will help you.

Comment: Hey Luke. Thanks for the email. Yes I do know about that script. I have been trying to use it to get it to work. Did you replace only files in the wp_posts table or all tables? I was only editing the wp_posts table but maybe I should be doing it to all tables. Thanks again

Comment: A replace on all tables. Remember to backup your DB before executing.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the options table that causes the issue.  Executing

```
update wp_options set option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_url', 'new_url');
```

As direct SQL on the DB should do the trick (replacing old_url and new_url with the correct urls).

Another path would be to define these two WP constants in your wp-config.php file, which will override the DB setting for the site URLs:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://sitehomeurl');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://siteurl');
```

And of course the caveat to back up your DB before running SQL against it applies.